# What kind of Twiml XML does Twilio need for a basic two-way call?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm a new developer and am researching implementing Twilio into my companies application. In researching and working with Twilio's Voice  API I've gotten the basic programmable voice running as seen below.

I know the URL contains the basic TWIML demo instructions for what Twilio should do with the call, my question is what if I just want a regular two-way call? No programmable voice or automated response just two people talking until one hangs up. Is that even possible with Twilio? Thanks in advance.

```
    client.calls
      .create({
         url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
         to: `+1${req.body.to}`,
         from: `+1${req.body.from}`
       })
      .then(call => {
          console.log(call.sid);
        }).catch(next)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, when the recipient answers the call, the code at `url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml'` will run. That's some generic TwiML provided by Twilio.

You'll need to change that to either your webhook (hosted on your server) or with a TwiML Bin (hosted at Twilio)  (https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins).

To connect two or more people you could put them in a conference if you respond with XML (TwiML) like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>Room 1234</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

For two people you would run your Node.js code twice changing the `to:` phone number for each recipient.

---

Docs:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference

---

Also, experiment with this, instead of the "conference" TwiML return a "dial" TwiML like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>415-123-4567</Dial>
</Response>
```

where `415-123-4567` is the number for the second person.

Comment: Interesting and helpful, but if I just call client.calls.create twice with the appropriate Twiml for Dial I just get dumped into the conference room on hold. How do I start the call immediately?"

Comment: The conference will start when you add the second person to the conference. Also if you only have two people, try a "dial" TwiML (I've updated the answer).

Comment: Hey I think that worked, accept if I'm writing this as a function how do I pass the number I want dialed into the XML file from Node?

Comment: If you're using a TwiML Bin I don't think you can. If you're returning XML from your server, then you could add it as query string parameter to the `url:` address and process there on your server side.

Comment: Interesting, You wouldn;t happen to have any resource links for how to do that would you?

Comment: Twilio docs (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/quickstart/node?code-sample=code-generate-twiml-to-say-a-message-1&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x#linkcode) and Twilio blog (https://www.twilio.com/blog/) are good resources. Also it's just about returning XML from your server side with whatever tech stack you're using. Try something and if you encounter a problem, you could ask another question to get help. Good luck.

Comment: You can pass in custom parameters using a TwiML Bin, if you want to go that route, How to use templates with TwiML Bins - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/230878368-How-to-use-templates-with-TwiML-Bins. You can move to Twilio Functions which provide a serverless experience using JavaScript. Another good article to look at is: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding, which provide many other alternative approaches for connecting two parties on a call.